# angular app shows page not found after being refreshed

Tags: angular, iis

This question has been asked a lot on the internet and I followed all of them but still, I get this nasty error.

Here is the error:

[image: TheError]

Here is my config file:

```
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

 <rewrite>

  <rules>

  <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">

    <match url=".*" />

      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

    </conditions>

    <action type="Rewrite" url="/WebPark/" />

     </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The name of the app is WebPark.

Comment: by adding provide:LocationStrategy,useClass:HashLocationStrategy} in my module.ts its working but it adds an extra # to my address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say to your web server(IIS) that use your angular router instead of your router.

After download and install the URL rewrite module from [this link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), you should add this config file to your IIS app folder:

`Web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  --><configuration>

<system.webServer>

  <rewrite>

    <rules>

      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">

        <match url=".*" />

        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

        </conditions>

        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />

      </rule>

    </rules>

  </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The above codes are complete file content.

Answer (score 0):

The difference from the recomendations for IIS setup in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) that i see is that your config is wrapped in `<configuration>` tag.

Comment: i removed it and still the same issue